# Which websites provide alternative listing of Mac App Store content?

Tags: mac-appstore

For iOS there is quite a few websites providing a alternative ways to browse through the many apps and also provides neat info about it's popularity.

What websites are there for the Mac App Store?

I already know of [AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/mac/).

The reason I'm asking is because I wish there was an "add app to wishlist" feature and a way to see comments across the world and an easier way to look through the lists beyond the limit of 50 apps (I know of the See All, but..). And for a lot of other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

[AppsOnSale](http://www.bigwhiteplanet.com/AppsOnSale) is a Mac app that shows an alternative listing of apps than the MAS.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Neuberg from TidBITS [reviewed a service](http://tidbits.com/article/12461) called "Appalicious" last fall. He was impressed with the various ways Appolicious had to slice and dice Mac App Store information. I haven't used the product myself, but it sounds like it may meet your need for a more sophisticated way of sorting through Apps.

Since Matt's review the program has been renamed Appcuity, and is [available here](http://appcuity.com/).